# How do I upload a converted drawable in android to Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

In my application, I am able to properly convert the drawable to an image and save it locally on the device. However, I'll need to push the image to Firebase and not save it locally. Here's what I have done.

```
public void saveImage () {

    int count = 0;

    File sdDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File subDirectory = new File(sdDirectory.toString() + "/Pictures/Paint");

    if (subDirectory.exists()) {
        File[] existing = subDirectory.listFiles();

        for (File file : existing) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".jpg") || file.getName().endsWith(".png")) {

                count++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        subDirectory.mkdir();
    }

    if (subDirectory.exists()) {
        File image = new File(subDirectory, "/drawing_" + (count + 1) + ".png");

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
            //The code below still doesn't save the image online in firebase.
            Uri file = Uri.fromFile(image);
//            StorageReference fileRef = reference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(file));
            StorageReference fileRef = reference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

            fileRef.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            Model model = new Model(uri.toString());
                    String modelId = root.push().getKey();
                    root.child(modelId).setValue(model);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Uploaded Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Uploading Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Boolean bool = mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);

            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "saved locally", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

It's always failing to upload the file but it successfully saves it locally. I've even just tried to display a notification upon a successful upload but it doesn't even get to the **addOnSuccessListener** talk less of the **onSuccessMethod**. I feel like I'm close but what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is ignoring all kinds of error, which make it really hard for you (let alone us) to troubleshoot. First off: stop catching errors and doing nothing with them, like in `} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {`. At the very least you should `Log.e("Storage", "Error uploading image", e)` them. Same for the `IOException`, and for `public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {`: if you log `e` there too, you may be able to find (in your logcat output) what is going wrong.

Comment: The logs showed me that it was a permissions issue and fixing it makes it work now. I appreciate it @FrankvanPuffelen. Do you think I should delete the question?

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer, as I see this sort of mistake regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ignoring all kinds of error, which make it really hard for you (let alone us) to troubleshoot.

First off: stop catching errors and doing nothing with them, like in `} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {`. At the very least you should log them with:

```
Log.e("Storage", "Error uploading image", e)
```

Same for the `IOException`, and for `public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {`: if you log `e` there too, you may be able to find (in your logcat output) what is going wrong.